# Moving around the lblas library and using it with the g++ compiler

Tags: c++, g++, blas

So on my current computer I Have a library to use BLAS functions, but I need to run my c++ program on an external server. I know how to transfer files to the server, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to find my blas library that's on my current computer and then how to link it to the compiler.

So here's the command I use current on my computer `g++ program -lblas`
And this works great. I run the program and everything is swell. How do I move this library to the external server?

Ideally, I'd like to move this library to the same folder as where my program resides and then link the compiler to that library somehow. Does anyone know how to do this?

If it helps, I know how to download a blas library and get a ".a" file out. I have no idea what to do from there though.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, simple question. I thought it was a lot more complicated.

For anyone that stumbles upon this, here's what you do:

Get your .a file. For me, I downloaded all the Makefile components necessary to make the .a file from here for blas: http://www.netlib.org/blas/

Next, put it in the same folder as your program if you want to do what I'm doing.

Finally, the command! Compiler, code, library

For me, this was `g++ program.cpp blas.a`